# Android: How do I make a fragment only appear when the map finishes loading?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to display a progress dialog for my map activity. The problem is, sometimes the code works and the map loads immediately, but other times it lags and takes forever leaving the user with a white screen and a google icon at the bottom left screen.

Below is basically the approach I'm using, but I can't see the progress dialog at all when the activity loads. Does anyone have any recommendations? Maybe I'm approaching this wrong.

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {
private GoogleMap mMap;
private ProgressDialog mapLoadingProgress;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


    mapLoadingProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
    mapLoadingProgress.setMessage("Loading map");
    mapLoadingProgress.show();
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mapLoadingProgress.dismiss();
    mMap = googleMap;

    markCurrentAddress();
    markMyLocation();
}
```

}

This is my layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.lusayo.mainproject.MapsActivity">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/branchSelector"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/nfb_maroon"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/branchSpinner"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/branchSelector"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.lusayo.mainproject.MapsActivity"
        map:uiRotateGestures="true"
        map:uiScrollGestures="true"
        map:uiTiltGestures="true"
        map:uiZoomControls="false"
        map:uiZoomGestures="true"
        map:uiMapToolbar="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/maps_preview"
    android:layout_above="@+id/map_controls" />


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_controls"
        android:background="@color/nfb_maroon"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <Button
            android:text="Get Directions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/nfb_maroon"
            android:textColor="#fff"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/getDirectionsButton"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to call:

```
mapLoadingProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);
mapLoadingProgress.setMessage("Loading map");
mapLoadingProgress.show();
```

before,

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) 
getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```

if it won't work try to move `setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);` to `onMapReady()` method after `mapLoadingProgress.dismiss();`